# Trying to connect Python to Access database by pyodbc, not sure what driver to use

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to an access database using pyodbc, but I am unsure which driver to use. Running the code

```
pyodbc.drivers()
```

I get

```
['SQL Server', 'PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)', 'PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)']
```

I figure I would want to have something like

```
['Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)']
```

But it is not listed even though I just reinstalled the driver from microsoft found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

So can I use one of the existing drivers (it does not appear to be the case when I try) or can I somehow let pyodbc find the correct driver ?

Comment: Check the bitness of your python install vs of the driver. For instance, if you are running a 32 bit driver and 64 bit python, the driver will not show up.

Comment: This turned out to indeed be the source of the problem, thank you